# android layout absolute position

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am new to android development and I have a question.
I am working on a game for android and I have to place some ImageViews on specific positions on my layout. For example I have an image of a kitchen as my background and I want to position an image of an apple on the top of the counter (it has to be always in the counter, in all screen sizes). What's the best way of doing this? 
I was using a relativeLayout, and changing the margins of my ImageView, but that doesn't seem to work really well.

Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_weight=".1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="(Character Request)"
            android:id="@+id/requestTxt"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="48px"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="342dp"
        android:id="@+id/characterLayout"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageBody"
            android:src="@drawable/body_canard"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageHead"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageHead" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageHead"
            android:src="@drawable/head_canard"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageEyes"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageEyes" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageEyes"
            android:src="@drawable/eyes_black"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageHat"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageHat" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="123dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageBody"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageBody"
            android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/mouthLayout"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageHat"
            android:src="@drawable/hats_bizarre"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageApple"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_apple"
            android:tag="pomme"
            android:layout_marginLeft="582dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageCheese"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_cheese"
            android:tag="fromage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="670dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageJuice"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_juice"
            android:tag="jus"
            android:layout_marginLeft="760dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"  />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageGrapes"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_grapes"
            android:tag="raisin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="582dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageBananas"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_bananas"
            android:tag="bananes"
            android:layout_marginLeft="760dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageMilk"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_milk"
            android:tag="lait"
            android:layout_marginLeft="490dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="260dp"  />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageCake"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_cake"
            android:tag="gâteau"
            android:layout_marginLeft="360dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"  />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageLettuce"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_lettuce"
            android:tag="laitue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="500dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"  />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageCorn"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_corn"
            android:tag="blé"
            android:layout_marginLeft="360dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"  />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageOrange"
            android:src="@drawable/kitchen_orange"
            android:tag="orange"
            android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"  />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight=".1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/audio"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_musique" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recommence"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One way is you have to set this image from code, or you have to create layout files for all required devices(like how you have done now).

Comment: @GangaNaidu do you know if there is any way I can set up the margins with percentage?